# how can i use preg_match with alphanumeric and unicode acceptance?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am going to build a multilingual website with PHP and need to have a preg_match which passes all Unicode characters and numbers.
i.e  I need it to pass English letters, Spanish letters,Italian letters and as you may know I don't want to pass other characters like ' " _ -  and ...

I want some thing like this :

```
$pattern='/^[unicode chars without \'-_;?]*$/u'; 
if(!preg_match($pattern, $url))
   echo #error;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not going to write something for you just because you asked. Show you've attempted something, and we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: i update question with some code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unicode property for letter is `\pL` so in `preg_match`:

```
preg_match('/^\pL+$/u', $string);
```

for an url you could add numbers `\pN` and dot:

```
preg_match('/^[\pL\pN.]+/u', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked perfect with Cyrillic and Latin, I am now sure it will work with other layouts also.