# Replace all but letters - explaination

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to modify a string and remove all but English letters (a-z, A-Z).  Note that white space should also be removed.

This post provides two answers [Remove everything except letters from PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264274/remove-everything-except-letters)

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/\PL/u', '', $old_string)

$new_string = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i','',$old_string);
```

I understand the second answer, but not the first.  The first had the highest votes.

Is the first the better answer?  Please explain what it is doing.

Comment: If the goal is to keep only english letters, the best answer is the second. However, this answer could be better if you add a quantifier: `/[^a-z]+/i`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte.  What makes adding the quantifier better?

Comment: Because you replace several consecutive characters at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means special unicode-character class qualifier. In this particular case, `L` means "letter". In PHP, `\P{xx}` is available so that's why `/\PL/u` will work.

Note, that `L` includes the following properties: `Ll`, `Lm`, `Lo`, `Lt` and `Lu` (check full list in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)). That means, `L` will include:

- Lower case letter (`Ll`)
- Modifier letter (`Lm`)
- Other letter (`Lo`)
- Title case letter (`Lt`)
- Upper case letter (`Lu`)

That means, `\PL` fits requirement "all except letters" better, but it will keep such things as French letters (because of `Lm`), while `[a-zA-Z]` (same as `/[a-z]/i`) is more strict and will leave only letters, specified in group.

And, of course, `\P{xx}` has sense only in terms of unicode, thus - `/u` modifier is mandatory there.

Answer (score 1):

`\pL` is the unicode property for letters
`\pN` is the unicode property for numbers

[a-z] doesn't take care of éàçè....

[how can i use preg_match with alphanumeric and unicode acceptance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787029/how-can-i-use-preg-match-with-alphanumeric-and-unicode-acceptance)

Comment: Hint: Your link does not exists.

Comment: Confirm lowercase `p` used in `\pL`.  Also, the purpose of `/u`?  Thanks